# Which is the best asynchronous Client side File Upload Control while working with .net(2.0+)

Tags: .net, ajax, validation, file-upload, upload

I am looking for a file upload control with following Features:

1)       It should be client side and also manage and check the file size at client side only.

2)       Also, the file type should be checked at client side only.

3)       File upload should upload the file asynchronously and also show the progress bar.

4)       Also, the file upload preferably should be ajax based and should show green icon when uploading is complete like in yahoo email.

5)       Also, it should work in medium trust with some folder permissions only.

The best I have come up with so far is the NeatUpload control. what alternatives do i have?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement no2: It's not possible to check file size at client-side using pure javascript unless you use client-side plugins/add-ons (.e.g: flash).

You may want to have a look at RadAsyncUpload. Very cool product:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload.aspx